# PostgreSQL - Update table with previous values ​from another table

Tags: postgresql, sum, sql-update, subquery

I want to update a table with the sum of a second table

This is the table 'x' that I want to update. Has a starting value and a closing value:

| id | op_date | initial_value | end_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 | 0 | 0 |

The table 'y' save the values ​​of the day:

| id | op_date | value_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-29 | 500 |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 200 |
| 2 | 2020-01-29 | 750 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 | 250 |

I want the result to look like this:

| id | op_date | initial_value | end_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 500 | 600 |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 600 | 800 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 750 | 850 |
| 2 | 2020-02-02 | 850 | 1100 |

I tried this script, but the process just runs it and doesn't finish it:

```
UPDATE x
SET 
    initial_value= (select sum(y.value_day) 
        from public.y where 
        y.op_date > '2020-11-01' and y.op_date < x.op_date 
        and y.id = x.id),
    end_value= (select sum(y.value_day) 
        from public.y where 
        y.op_date between '2020-11-01' and x.op_date 
        and y.id = x.id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **window function**. To understand window function more you can look this **[link](https://modern-sql.com/blog/2019-02/postgresql-11)**.
At first i am writing query to select the value.

```
select id,op_date,
sum(value_day) over (
    partition by y.id   
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  )-value_day as initial_value,
sum(value_day) over (
    partition by y.id   
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) as end_value
from y

;
```

This is your update query.

```
UPDATE x
set initial_value=s_statement.initial_value,
end_value=s_statement.end_value
from 
(select id,op_date,
sum(value_day) over (
    partition by y.id    
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  )-value_day as initial_value,
sum(value_day) over (
    partition by y.id   
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) as end_value
from y) s_statement
where x.id=s_statement.id 
and x.op_date=s_statement.op_date

;
```

Let me know if its ok with you.

Comment: Nice, thank your for your answer. It has helped me a lot.